# Is Hadoop File System Used by All NoSQL Frameworks?

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, cassandra, bigdata, nosql

I an new to Big Data; obviously most applications using NoSQL frameworks such as MongoDB, CouchDb, and Cassandra require access to huge amount of data.  Now, my question is if all these NoSQL tools use Hadoop file system as their storage, or some how file system of their own?

If they use Hadoop file system, then do they have an easy way to integrate with Hadoop file system?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they do not use HDFS by default. Many of the NoSQL databases have been made to scale out well. That is, the data can be separated onto a bunch of regular non-HDFS machines and if configured correctly (in some cases this could be a big if) they will operate efficiently.

So they do not use HDFS for their scaling systems, but they can be integrated with Hadoop

[Documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-hadoop/) and [Webinar](http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/webinar-mongodb-and-hadoop-working-together-provide-business-insights) about MongoDB and Hadoop.

[Blog](https://mpouttuclarke.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/couchdb-and-hadoop/) about CouchDB and Hadoop.

[Documentation](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/cluster_architecture/hadoop_integration) about Cassandra and Hadoop.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that MongoDB are mostly meant to work with a few terabytes of data (as they are supposed to provide fast, and online processing of data), and thus in most cases are meant to simply work with local file systems, while Hadoop is mostly suited to work with huge data and offline?  I'm sure MongoDB can handle hundreds of terabytes, but I think it is really not meant for that.

Comment: I would say that generally that is a fair statement. Hadoop is definitely meant for doing data analysis on very large datasets (petabytes, exabytes, etc). MongoDB is meant to act as a database that serves an  application and which can be scaled out to many machines. If the queries in an application were optimized to work very well with a sharded cluster, then it should be able to handle a large amount of data. I'm not sure where the bottlenecks will show up and I'm sure it's application and hardware specific.